# installing playwright dependencies for AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, playwright, amazon-ecr, playwright-python

I have a small RestAPI service that uses playwright to scrape data and return it to the client.
Locally everything works perfect, also with docker.

My goal is to upload it to AWS ECR and use the image in a lambda function.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY requirements/prod.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip install -r prod.txt
RUN playwright install 
RUN playwright install-deps 

ADD src ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD ["main.handler"]
```

When it get to 'RUN playwright install-deps' it fails with the following messege:

```
 > [6/7] RUN playwright install-deps:
#10 0.668 BEWARE: your OS is not officially supported by Playwright; installing dependencies for Ubuntu as a fallback.
#10 0.669 Installing dependencies...
#10 0.676 sh: apt-get: command not found
#10 0.678 Failed to install browser dependencies
#10 0.678 Error: Installation process exited with code: 127
```

How can I install the requierd dependencies?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the OS that public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8 is using is not one of the supported by playwright. Maybe you can use another image with Ubuntu?

Comment: But how do I know it is compatible with AWS ECR?